# More effective way to put values in object for checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Sorry my kind of vague question , but it was hard to find a very good title.

This is my jQuery:

```
var selection_info = {};
var housenr = $("#housenr_export")[0].checked;
if (housenr === true) {
    selection_info.housenr = 1;
}
else {
    selection_info.housenr = 0;
}

var phone= $("#phone_export")[0].checked;
if (phone=== true) {
    selection_info.phone = 1;
}
else {
    selection_info.phone = 0;
}
```

I'm looking for a better way to set the `selection_info.housenr` and `selection_info.phone` based on whether or not the checkboxes are checked. It works but it's not nice :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a reason to use numbers to determine true/false values and if you're going to use jQuery, then use all that jQuery has to offer.

```
var selection_info = {};
selection_info.housenr =  $("#housenr_export").is(":checked");
selection_info.phone = $("#phone_export").is(":checked");
```

Simplified and values actually represent the status.

Comment: Simply perfect! Thank you!